# JQuery .fadein() data insert at top instead of bottom

Tags: jquery, comments, clipbucket

Right now I have ClipBucket, and I'm editing the comments part of it.

When comments are posted, the new comment shows up at the bottom of the list, it needs to show up at the top when posted.

```
var formObjectData = $('#'+form_id).serialize()+'&mode=add_comment';

$.post(page,formObjectData,
    function(data)
    {
        if(!data)
            alert("No data");
        else
        {

            $("#add_comment_button").attr("disabled","");

            $("#add_comment_result").css("display","block");
            if(data.err!='')
            {
                $("#add_comment_result").html(data.err);
            }
            if(data.msg!='')
                $("#add_comment_result").html(data.msg);

            if(data.cid)
            {
                get_the_comment(data.cid,"#latest_comment_container");
                $("#"+form_id).slideUp(1500).delay(10000).fadeIn(1500).val("");
            }
        }
    },'json');
}

function get_the_comment(id,div)
{

    $(div).html(loading);
    $.post(page, 
    {     
        mode : 'get_comment',
        cid : id
    },
    function(data)
    {
        if(!data)
            alert("No data");
        else
        {        
            $(div).css("display","none");
            $(div).html(data).fadeIn("slow");
        }
    },'text');
}
```

Also, on the line where I have:

```
$("#"+form_id).slideUp(1500).delay(10000).fadeIn(1500).val("");"
```

Is there something I can add to this to make it clear and reset the form? It shows back up with the old text, and if a new comment comes in, it simply appears to edit that first one even though it posted a new one.

Also, is there a button I can add that will refresh the comments listing without refreshing the page?

HTML:

```
`comments.html
{if $comments}
<div style="height:10px"></div>
    {foreach from=$comments.comments item=comment}
        {include file="$style_dir/blocks/comments/comment.html" comment=$comment type=$type parents=$comments.parents}
    {/foreach}

    <div style="height:10px"></div>


{else}
    <div id="latest_comment_container">
    <div align="center" class="no_comments">
        {lang code='no_comments' assign=no_comments} {$no_comments|sprintf:$object_type}
    </div>
    </div>

{/if}
{if $comments}
<div id="latest_comment_container"></div>
{/if}


add_comment.html:
<div class="add_comment_box" id="add_comment">
<h2 style="margin:0px">{lang code='grp_add_comment'}</h2>


<div id="add_comment_result" class="add_comment_result" style="display:none"></div>
{if $userquery->login_check('',true) || $Cbucket->configs.anonym_comments == 'yes'}
<form name="comment_form" method="post" action="" id="comment_form" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="reply_to" id="reply_to" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="obj_id" id="obj_id" value="{$id}">

    {if !$userquery->login_check('',true) && $Cbucket->configs.anonym_comments == 'yes'}
    <label for="name" class="label">{lang code='name'}</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="input"><br>
    <label for="email" class="label">{lang code='email_wont_display'}</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email"  class="input"><br>
    {else}
    Name : {$userquery->username}<br>
    {/if}

    {ANCHOR place='before_compose_box'}
    <textarea name="comment" id="comment_box" cols="45" rows="5"  class="input" style="width:97%" ></textarea>

    <div style="height:10px"></div>


      {if config('comments_captcha')=='all' || ( config('comments_captcha')=='guests' && !$userquery->login_check('',true) )}

      <div style="width:auto; float:left; ">
    <strong>{lang code='please_enter_confimation_ode'}</strong>

        {assign var=captcha value=func->get_captcha()}
        {if $captcha} 
            {if $captcha.show_field}
                <label class="label" for="captcha">Verification Code</label><br />
                    {load_captcha captcha=$captcha load=field field_params = ' id="captcha" class="input" '}
               <div class="clearfix"></div>
            {/if}
            <label class="label">&nbsp;</label>

                {load_captcha captcha=$captcha load=function}

            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        {/if}

        </div>
    {/if}

    <div style="width:auto; float:left;padding-left:10px; padding-bottom:10px">{ANCHOR place='after_compose_box'}</div>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="{$type}" />
    <div style="margin-top:2px" ><input type="button" name="add_comment" id="add_comment_button" value="{lang code='user_add_comment'}" 
    class="cb_button" onclick="add_comment_js('comment_form','{$type}'){ANCHOR place='onClickAddComment'}"></div>
 <div style="margin-top:2px" ><input type="button" name="reload" id="reload_comment_button" value="Reload" 
    class="cb_button" onclick="reload_comment_js('comment_form','{$type}'){ANCHOR place='onClickAddComment'}"></div>
</form>
{else}
    {lang code='please_login_to_comment'}
{/if}
</div>

comment.html:
{if marked_spammed($comment)}
    {assign var='comment_attr' value='style="display:none"'}
    {assign var='spam_attr' value='style="display:block"'}
{else}
{assign var='comment_attr' value=''}
    {assign var='spam_attr' value='style="display:none"'}
{/if}

    <div id="comment_{$comment.comment_id}" class="comment clearfix" {$comment_attr}>
    <div class="user_com_thumb_con">
        <img src="{$userquery->getuserthumb($comment)}" class="user_com_thumb"  />
    </div>
    <div class="comm_other">
        <div class="user_bar">
        <div style="width:70%; float:left">
        {lang code='user_commented_time' assign='user_commented_time'}
        {assign var="nicetime" value=$comment.date_added|niceTime}
        {if $comment.userid !='' && $comment.userid!=0}
            {assign var="comm_link" value=$userquery->profile_link($comment)}
            {assign var="comm_owner" value=$comment.username}
        {else}
            {assign var="comm_id" value="#comment_"}
            {assign var="comm_link" value=$comment.comment_id}
            {assign var="comm_owner" value=$comment.anonym_name}       
        {/if}

        {$user_commented_time|sprintf:"$comm_id$comm_link":$comm_owner:$nicetime}

        </div>
        <div style="width:28%; float:right" align="right"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="to_reply('{$comment.comment_id}')">{lang code='reply'}</a> | <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="spam_comment('{$comment.comment_id}','{$type}','{$type_id}')">{lang code='spam'}</a>

        {if has_access('admin_del_access') || $comment.userid==userid() || $comment.type_owner_id==userid()} | <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="delete_comment('{$comment.comment_id}','{$type}','{$type_id}')">{lang code='delete'}</a>{/if}</div>
        </div>

        <div class="comment_cont">

        {if $comment.parent_id}
            {assign var=parentid value=$comment.parent_id}
            {assign var=thisParent value=$parents.$parentid}

            {if $thisParent}
            <div style="padding:3px; margin:5px; background-color:#CCC">

                {if $thisParent.username}@{$thisParent.username} : 
                {/if}{$thisParent.comment|comment}
            </div>
            {/if}
        {/if}

        {$comment.comment|comment}

        </div>

        {if $type=='video' && $comments_voting=='yes' && $Cbucket->configs.comment_rating}
        <div class="comment_rating_cont"><span class="thumb_up" onclick="rate_comment('{$comment.comment_id}','up','{$type}','{$type_id}')">Thumbs Up</span><span class="thumb_down" onclick="rate_comment('{$comment.comment_id}','down','{$type}','{$type_id}')">Thumbs Down</span><span id="comment_rating_{$comment.comment_id}" class="comment_rating">{$comment.vote|comment_rating}</span></div>
        {/if}

    </div>
    </div>

    <div id="spam_comment_{$comment.comment_id}" class="spam" {$spam_attr} >
        {lang code='marked_as_spam_comment_by_user' assign='marked_as_spam_comment_by_user'}

        {if $comment.username}{$marked_as_spam_comment_by_user|sprintf:$comment.username}{else}{$marked_as_spam_comment_by_user|sprintf:$comment.anonym_name}{/if} | <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="delete_comment('{$comment.comment_id}')">{lang code='delete'}</a>
    </div>`
```

Comment: Just my opinion, but you should avoid mixing a space-delimited `if` statement when it has an `else` that is multi-line (and requires curly braces).

Comment: I didn't write it, only added that one line I referenced to below the code I pasted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [.prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) or [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) if you want to add content each time a new comment is submitted.

With [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) you can load e.g. a file in a div:

```
$('#selector').load('comments.php');
```

**Edit:**

**Prepending comments:** E.g.: `#comments` is your div where all your comments are shown. In this case, every comment has it's own div with the class `.comments_box`. Now everytime a comment is added, you prepend a new comment box to #comments.

```
$('#comments').prepend('<div class="comments_box">' + data + '</div>');
```

**Reloading comments:** E.g.: in your div `#comments` you include the file `comments.php` (`<?php include('comments.php'); ?>`). Now you want to reload (or simply load) comments.php again in the div #comments when you click on the class `.reload`:

```
$('.reload').click(function() {

    $('#comments').load('comments.php');

});
```

Comment: I'm completely green here.. can you please describe more?

Comment: can you post the html as well?

Comment: Posted... I've been stuck on this all night. Thanks for the help. Can you also help me with the other 2 questions above?

Comment: Thanks. I'll get back to you tomorrow. It's almost 4am and I really have to get some sleep. Hope that's okay for you.

Comment: Okay will check back in tomorrow

Comment: I think I've got an inelegant solution for you. But it would be better moving this discussion to a chat and working on a live example.

Comment: I just said I don't have enough to move it to chat.

Comment: If you can give me some examples or something to try I can try it. I'm desperate to get these issues fixed.